# Definition of a real valued function being linear

Tags: real-analysis

I was reading a solution for a question that asked to show a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is linear given $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$.

The proof showed that $f(x)=f(1)x$ and $f(0)=0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. I understand the proof but I dont understand why this showed $f$ is linear.

Since for a map to be linear it has to map 0 to 0 (which is proved) and additivity (which is given by the question) and Homogeneity for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $f(\lambda x)=\lambda f(x)$. I guess I can see that from the proof we can conclude $f(\lambda x)=\lambda xf(1)=\lambda f(x)$. Or when it comes to linearity of real functions it is a bit different?

Thanks!

Comment: I think $f(0)=0$ would follow from $f(x)=f(1)x$?  (Not related to your question, just a side note.)

Comment: For "linear" you need a field.  In this case, $\mathbb R$ is a vector space over the field $\mathbb Q$.  That means, we have to show $f(\lambda x) = \lambda f(x)$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb Q$ and $x \in \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of linearity for $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ (over the field $\Bbb{R}$) is the same as always. We can consider $\Bbb{R}$ as a vector space over the field $\Bbb{R}$, so linearity means you have to show additivity and homogeneity:

- additivity: for all $x,y\in\Bbb{R}$, $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$
- homogeneity: for all $\lambda\in\Bbb{R}$ and all $x\in\Bbb{R}$, $f(\lambda x)=\lambda f(x)$.

The purpose of this problem is to show that for $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$, continuity and additivity imply homogeneity, and thus you get linearity. If you drop continuity, you can fail to get homogeneity. So, bottom line is $\Bbb{R}$ is a weird but at the same time, cool place to be.

As for why $f(x)=f(1)x$ “showed it is linear”, well whoever wrote the proof (reasonably) expected that it is obvious enough to conclude from there. But yes, what you wrote is correct for homogeneity: $f(\lambda x)=\lambda xf(1)=\lambda f(x)$ (where we have to use associativity of multiplication and that $1$ is the multiplicative identity in the field… but these are all details you should fill in yourself).

More generally, you can show that for any field $\Bbb{F}$ and vector space $V$ over $\Bbb{F}$, a map $T:\Bbb{F}\to V$ is linear if and only if it is homogeneous (in which case, $T(x)=xT(1)$ for all $x\in\Bbb{F}$).

Comment: +1 and I liked "$\mathbb{R} is a weird but at the same time, cool place to be".

Answer (score 1):

It proved that the function is of the form $f(x)=ax$ for some number $a$ and all such functions are linear.

Comment: I see, so this must be some if and only if proposition of a function being linear.